# Img and Text Issues with Margins

Tags: icons, text-alignment

I seem to always have issues with creating a div that contains a icon/img on the left with a title and subtitle on the right.

Can someone let me know if there's an easier way to do this and point me to a tutorial.  Also for some reason I can't get the the "li-box" class to take on a margin.

Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/pLnydmw0/1/

```
<ul class="map-uk-tooltip">
    <li class="li-box">
        <img class="map-uk-tooltip-img" src="http://yeabruh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/icon-uae-100MW.png" />
        <div class="box-for-text">
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-tilte">DEWA Phase 2 Solar PV</div>
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-client">SunEdison</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li-box">
        <img class="map-uk-tooltip-img" src="http://yeabruh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/icon-uae-100MW.png" />
        <div class="box-for-text">
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-tilte">DEWA Phase 2 Solar PV</div>
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-client">SunEdison</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li-box">
        <img class="map-uk-tooltip-img" src="http://yeabruh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/icon-uae-100MW.png" />
        <div class="box-for-text">
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-tilte">DEWA Phase 2 Solar PV</div>
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-client">SunEdison</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this should work for you.

I found a couple of inconsistencies:

1) In your markup (above) you have `classes` (eg. `<ul class="map-uk-tooltip">`), but in your fiddle you have `id`s (eg. `<ul id="map-uk-tooltip">`) - `id`s are useful for javascript, but when it comes to nested elements and CSS specificity, it tends to be a lot easier to work with nested classes. So I have gone with your markup above (not your markup in the fiddle).

2) In your markup above, you have: `<div class="map-uk-tooltip-tilte">`.
   In your fiddle markup, you have: `id="map-uk-tooltip-tilte"`.
   In your fiddle CSS, you have: `#map-uk-tooltip-title`

I'm sure I don't need to say this, but... check your markup and styles for typos!

What else...

3) When you want to resume normal flow after declaring a `float:`, you need to clear: (either `clear:left;`, `clear:right;` or `clear:both;`). If you don't `clear:` the document's normal flow will not resume and various subsequent elements will continue to fit themselves around the floated element.

4) When you declare a `float:` it's pretty good practice to always declare the width of the floated element.

All that said, try this:

```css
.map-uk-tooltip {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.map-uk-tooltip li {
    clear:left;
    height: 200px;
}

.map-uk-tooltip-img, .box-for-text {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: 160px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="map-uk-tooltip">
    <li class="li-box">
        <img class="map-uk-tooltip-img" src="http://yeabruh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/icon-uae-100MW.png" />
        <div class="box-for-text">
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-title">DEWA Phase 2 Solar PV</div>
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-client">SunEdison</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li-box">
        <img class="map-uk-tooltip-img" src="http://yeabruh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/icon-uae-100MW.png" />
        <div class="box-for-text">
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-title">DEWA Phase 2 Solar PV</div>
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-client">SunEdison</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li-box">
        <img class="map-uk-tooltip-img" src="http://yeabruh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/icon-uae-100MW.png" />
        <div class="box-for-text">
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-title">DEWA Phase 2 Solar PV</div>
            <div class="map-uk-tooltip-client">SunEdison</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```